# center h1 in the middle of screen

Tags: html, css, text-align

How can I center horizontally and vertically a text? I don't want to use position absolute because I try with it and my other div getting worse. Is there another way to do that ?

```css
div {
    height: 400px;
    width: 800px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>This is title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the `h1` centered within the `div` or the `div` centered within the viewport/screen? Please clarify,

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can use display flex it enables a flex context for all its direct children, and with flex direction establishes the main-axis, thus defining the direction flex items are placed in the flex container

```
div{
  height: 400px;
  width: 800px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Hopefully OP doesn't need to support internet explorer.

Comment: IE 10/11 is pretty fine with flexbox.

Answer (score 5):

Just do this, which works on every browser:

```
div{
     height: 400px;
     width: 800px;
     background: red;
     line-height: 400px;
     text-align: center;
}
```

The `line-height` property specifies the line height (which centres it vertically), and the `text-align:center` place it directly in the centre horizontally.

Comment: it work also for divs ? because i put this in my website it didnt work

Comment: @Dina divs are block elements, so no. If you want it to work on a div, set the div style to `display: inline`. You should use `span` for inline text.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
  <style>
div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}</style>
<h1>This is title</h1>
</div>
```

With `position: fixed` you set the position to a fixed value, and with `top` and `left` both set to `50%` you'll get it in the middle of the screen.

Good luck coding!

Here is some more information: https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/

Answer (score -1):

```css
.container {
    display: table;
}
.centered {
    display: table-cell;
      height: 400px;
      width: 800px;
      background: red;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="centered">
  <h1>This is title</h1>
</div>
</div>
```